# What are the pre-requisite of a dataset's measurement type before Principal Component Analysis can be used?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, dimensionality-reduction, measurement

Must all the measured data be discrete, continuous, nominal or ordinal? What are some of the transformation techniques that can be used?